# rxjs, subscription.unsubscribe is not a function?

Tags: rxjs

I don't know why `subscription.unsubscribe` is not a function.

I can't figure out.

```js
const Rx = require("rx");

const observable = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
  observer.next(1);
  observer.next(2);
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    observer.next('nmb');
  }, 1000);

  return function unsubscribe() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
});

const subscription = observable.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

setTimeout(() => {
  subscription.unsubscribe();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue is encountered when writing code against the rxjs 5 api but referencing rxjs 4.

Comment: The problem is `rxjs` version. For v5 is `subscription.unsubscribe()`, for v4, is `subscrption.dispose()`